# Next.js - net::ERR_ABORTED 404 - wrong chunks links in index.html

Tags: next.js

I am deploying a new branch, with some features.
On 1 specific page it is getting several 404:

The header of this page is loading:

```
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/41f7fd9dc1a6f1e05830.css" as="style">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/41f7fd9dc1a6f1e05830.css" data-n-g="">
<noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-917a29e0b939a068b2f9.js" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-9d47fe6f5703c9f8e12f.js" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/f10e284a-630cd02b2b3bf56206d3.js" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/4322cd96-d78235cad87d066720fd.js" defer=""></script>
<script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-a40ef1678bae11e696dba45124eadd70.js"></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/dff27125-d92a8c54a93affce74f4.js" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/988-f9dea6dba032dfd2a9db.js" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/admin-e8710a3f7a13db306302.js" defer="">
</script>
<script src="/_next/static/luE6TfbJPNV1iIllYuv5s/_buildManifest.js" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/luE6TfbJPNV1iIllYuv5s/_ssgManifest.js" defer=""></script></head>
```

And it is getting:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
webpack-917a29e0b939a068b2f9.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
_app-9d47fe6f5703c9f8e12f.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
_buildManifest.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
_ssgManifest.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Those files are not present.
In the chunks folder I see:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  18332 Dec 29 21:14 310-9b401e8f32b93a9f310f.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  74350 Dec 29 21:14 4322cd96-d78235cad87d066720fd.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  30214 Dec 29 21:14 470-cfb55a099e7ca11be038.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 484930 Dec 29 21:14 617777a1.1355af0053c0d8407a5e.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  46243 Dec 29 21:14 643-990eae0e72368e8be577.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 126349 Dec 29 21:14 73-6dd7b239bf04015a4f23.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 180152 Dec 29 21:14 864-4edf9f3191dfab9a263d.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  37575 Dec 29 21:14 866-e51611e5772de58971f0.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    498 Dec 29 21:14 872.7927b9fdb3e86e5c5d9e.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  14106 Dec 29 21:14 988-f9dea6dba032dfd2a9db.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 813288 Dec 29 21:14 dff27125-d92a8c54a93affce74f4.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 400175 Dec 29 21:14 f10e284a-630cd02b2b3bf56206d3.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 131644 Dec 29 21:14 framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  77263 Dec 29 21:14 main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Dec 29 21:14 pages
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  91434 Dec 29 21:14 polyfills-a40ef1678bae11e696dba45124eadd70.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4012 Dec 29 21:14 webpack-1d7ce7d0a6b912ec2136.js
```

And in the css folder only:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 532833 Dec 29 21:14 6889a1734a7ff9e5ae36.css
```

I tried to rebuild the project in many ways but still the same.
I tried to re run it the usual way `npm run build && pm2 restart devBook`

and also  with  `npm run dev`:

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "node server.js -p $PORT",
        "watch-dev": "next",
        "build": "next build",
        "startdev": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js -p $PORT",
        "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js -p $PORT",
        "prod": "BASE_PATH=/out next build && next export",
        "prod2": "next build && next export",
        "start2": "next start",
        "postbuild": "next-sitemap"
    },
```

Here is the bulding log:

```
> next build

info  - Loaded env from /var/www/mysite/.env
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types  
warn  - No ESLint configuration detected. Run next lint to begin setup
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
Warning: You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to `getInitialProps` in `pages/_app`. This does not opt-out pages with `getStaticProps`
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/opt-out-auto-static-optimization

info  - Collecting page data  
Page                              Size     First Load JS
┌ λ /                             197 B           161 kB
├   /_app                         0 B            87.8 kB
├ λ /404                          2.25 kB          90 kB
├ λ /thepagethathasthisproblem                        354 kB          447 kB
└ λ /thankyou                     1.48 kB         162 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all     87.8 kB
  ├ chunks/framework.c93ed7.js    42.6 kB
  ├ chunks/main.89e612.js         23.3 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app.fcb7f3.js   20 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack.1d7ce7.js      1.89 kB
  └ css/6889a1734a7ff9e5ae36.css  74 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
   (ISR)     incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)


> mojosa@2.8.0 postbuild
> next-sitemap

Loaded env from /var/www/mysite/.env

> mojosa@2.8.0 postbuild
> next-sitemap

Loaded env from /var/www/mysite/.env
Use --update-env to update environment variables
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [sitename](ids: [ 1 ])
[PM2] [sitename](1) ✓
```

The page where the problem is happening didn't have any change in this branch.

Can anybody help please?